# What do I do when tf2ss() returns empty matrices?

Tags: function, matlab, matrix, transfer, state-space

I'm iterating a single-input-single-output linear system by sending inputs to it and getting outputs from it. The nominator and denominator of the transfer function of the system are represented by `Nom` and `Den` in the code respectively.

`Nom` and `Den` are calculated after some complex operations on some polynomials, so I don't have prior information on the degree of these polynomials. The only thing I know is that the system is proper (i.e.; the degree of `Den` is greater than or equal to the degree of `Nom`).

My code goes like this:

```
% ...

Nom = (...);  % calculated after some complex operations
Den = (...);  % calculated after some complex operations

[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss(Nom, Den);
x = zeros(size(B));  % state vector
xp = x;              % derivative of the state vector

% ...

for t = 0 : SAMPLING_PERIOD : TIME_END
    % ...
    xp = A * x + B * u;    % 'u' is some scalar input, calculated in the code previously
    y  = C * x + D * u;    % 'y' is some irrelevant output signal, to be used in somewhere else in the code
    x  = xp * SAMPLING_PERIOD;
    % ...
end

% ...
```

When `Den` is 0<sup>th</sup> order (which requires `Nom` to be 0<sup>th</sup> order as well), `tf2ss()` returns empty matrices for `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. This is somewhat problematic in my other parts of code. I need these matrices to be at least 1-by-1.

So, my question is, what equivalent non-empty matrices can I use instead of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` for those who return empty? For example, can I assume that all empty matrices are 1-by-1 zero matrices?

---

Example:

`[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss([1], [2])`
returns
`A = []     % Empty matrix`
`B = []     % Empty matrix`
`C = []     % Empty matrix`
`D = 0.5    % 1-by-1 matrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimelty, you need to understand what the output is providing.

The way the code is written for tf2ss, `if size(den) = 1` then `a = b =c =[]`

The reason for that is because you are no longer providing a differential equation, and are separating the differential equation component from the output.

For your purposes, knowing it's a Single Input Single Output system, `A` and `B` can be random matrices, and as long as you have x*C = [0], you should be fine. The idea is there is no real "state to the equation". However, for your purposes, you should instruct Matlab that there is only a single state which is not influenced by it's derivative (i.e. the present state, which is accurate for a pure gain system) with A = B = C = 0

While Matlab may see a difference when building the system, the reality is they are the same:

```
[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss([1], [2]);
H2 = ss(0,0,0,D);
H1 = ss(A,B,C,D);
bode(H1/ H2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty matrixes are definitely not `1x1` zeros. If you need to mark somehow that the result is not a number, but still have size of `1x1`, try returning `NaN` instead.

Comment: I beg to differ, that is exactly the equivalent output